# laravel 4 ErrorException file_put_contents

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel

I am deploying  a laravel app in GAE. It worked perfectly. But after i made composer update shows the error:

```
ErrorException
file_put_contents(/base/data/home/apps/s~national-test/1.375570506759026970/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Read-only file system
```

What is happening?

Comment: Something (you haven't given enough information to say what) is trying to write to the filesystem. That isn't possible on App Engine.

Comment: when i installed , i had to give the command  cacls -R 777 to storage file (but i don't remember the exact way how I did this). But now its not working. I am working on windows 8

Comment: and after that i worked. Now that i made composer update folder composer.json inside storage is deleted, it's not there.

Comment: @Greg do you know how is the command correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
chmod 777 -R /base/data/home/apps/s~national-test/1.375570506759026970/app/storage/
```

That should set the correct permission on your storage folder.